# Ncurses window zoom

Tags: c, linux, ncurses

Im using ncurses to create a game on c, but the window i created based on the game settings (LINES AND COLS) is too small and its hard to see what's happening on the game.
Is there any way to increase the size of the window(Without changing the LINES and COLS) to make the window more visible and allow users to see what's going on the game ?

Code :

```
void drawGame(RESPONSE resp) {
int i, j;
WINDOW *game_win;
init_pair(2, COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_GREEN);
game_win = newwin(resp.width, resp.height, 1, 1);
wbkgd(game_win, COLOR_PAIR(2));
keypad(game_win, TRUE);
noecho();
curs_set(FALSE);

for (int i = 0; i < resp.width; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < resp.height; ++j) {
        if (resp.maze[i][j].type == indestrutiveBlock)
            mvwaddch(game_win, i, j, '#');
        if (resp.maze[i][j].type == destrutiveBlock)
            mvwaddch(game_win, i, j, '*');
        if (resp.maze[i][j].type == object)
            mvwaddch(game_win, i, j, '@');
        if (resp.maze[i][j].type == enemy)
            mvwaddch(game_win, i, j, 'e');
        if (resp.maze[i][j].type == emptyBlock)
            mvwaddch(game_win, i, j, '.');
    }
}

wrefresh(game_win);
}
```

Comment: In most OSes, it's up to the user to set the console font size to his liking. It's beyond ncurses purposes.

Comment: You might want to handle `SIGWINCH`. Read  [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) &  [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html)

Comment: BTW, for a game, I would consider using some GUI, e.g. [libsdl](https://www.libsdl.org/), [GTK](http://gtk.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use video highlights such as bold, or reverse (or even other colors) for the text drawn using these calls:

```
            mvwaddch(game_win, i, j, '.');
```

That last parameter is more than a *character*, it can have flags combined with it, e.g.,

```
            mvwaddch(game_win, i, j, '.' | A_REVERSE | A_BOLD);
```

Comment: The highlights helped a little , but i meant if there is not a way to make like a zoom in on the window .Sorry for my bad english :D

Comment: no - there's no way to do that.  That's why we have video highlights :-)